# Making table cell click events align more with "MVVM"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a table that is being populated from a `shiftCells` array in my view model.  There are ~8 different types of cells that are rendered, and I need to perform a different action for each of them depending on which cell is clicked.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this in the view model, so that the view controller only cares about the end result (so it can navigate to a new view controller, etc...), but I'm struggling to figure out a way to organize it properly.  Here's what my current tableview click binding looks like in the VC:

```swift
    shiftsTableViewController
                .cellSelection
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (cellType: ShiftSelectionsTableViewCellType) in
                    guard let sSelf = self else { return }
                    switch cellType {
                      case .cellTypeA(let viewModel):
                          self.performSomeAction(viewModel: viewModel)
                      ...etc...
                    }
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Based on the type of cell, I perform a custom action (it might be a network request, to which the result would go into a new VC that is navigated to, or it may be something else).  Here's what `performSomeAction` could look like:

```swift
    func performSomeAction(viewModel: ShiftTypeCellViewModel) {
            self.networkService
                .perform(
                    shiftId: viewModel.shiftId, // notice i need data from cell vm
                    pin: self.viewModel.pin, // i also need data from root vm
                    photoURL: self.viewModel.imageURL)
                .subscribe(onNext: { result in
                    self.navigateToPage(result: result)
                }, onError: { error in
                    // show error banner
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
```

So with ~8 different types of cells, I have 8 methods that all do something a little bit differently.  Should I move these methods into the VM?  Should I move this methods into the cells VM and handle the click event directly in the cell view?  Advice / an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you provided in your question, here's what I think I would end up with:

In viewDidLoad of VC:

```
let result = viewModel.generateRequest(forCell: tableView.rx.modelSelected(ShiftSelectionsTableViewCellType.self).asObservable())
    .flatMapLatest { [networkService] arg in
        (networkService?.perform(shitId: arg.shiftId, pin: arg.pin, photoURL: arg.photoURL) ?? .empty())
            .materialize()
    }
    .share(replay: 1)

result.compactMap { $0.element }
    .bind(onNext: { [weak self] result in
        self?.navigateToPage(result: result)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

result.compactMap { $0.error }
    .bind(onNext: { error in
        // show error banner
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In ViewModel:

```
func generateRequest(forCell cell: Observable<ShiftSelectionsTableViewCellType>) -> Observable<(shiftId: String, pin: String, photoURL: URL)> {
    return cell.map { [pin, imageURL] cellType in
        switch cellType {
        case .cellTypeA(let viewModel):
            return (shiftId: viewModel.shiftId, pin: pin, photoURL: imageURL)
        }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

This way, all the side effects are in the VC and all the logic is in the VM. The above puts the `networkService` in the VC because it is a side effecting object.

Comment: I really like this approach - it also allows me to eliminate a lot of boilerplate code that I'd otherwise have.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your viewController should only handle the UI with the cell selection Then your view model should be the facilitator of the data. Also, I would try to avoid having your cells have anything more than UI code, if possible.

```
// ViewController
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    viewModel.performSomeAction(indexPath: indexPath)
}

func setupObservables() {
    viewModel.outputs.reloadRelay
        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let uwSelf = self else { return }
            uwSelf.tableView.reloadData()
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}


// ViewModel

// This BehaviorRelay is kinda silly but i'm and trying to demonstrate a trigger that your viewcontroller can listen for to update your UI
var reloadRelay: BehaviorRelay<Bool> = BehaviorRelay(value: false)

func performSomeAction(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
    case (1, _):
    // Make a network call then update your data
    service.randomCall(id: id)
        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { result in
            // Update data with result response data
            self.navigateToPage(result: result)
    }, onError: { [weak self] error in
        print(error)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    case (2, _):
    // Update your data then reload the table
    reloadRelay.accept(true)
    case (3, _):
    // Do something else
    case (4, 0):
    // Do something else
    ...
    default: break
    })
}
```